# Walk/Run round;laps (Take/run)

Tags: word-usage

If someone walks/runs around a ground (or maybe anything like school.)

> I walked one round. (Or should it be "lap"?)
>   (Or: I've walked  ten rounds)
>
> I ran one round. (Or should it be "laps" instead of "rounds"?)
>   (Or:I've run ten rounds; I ran ten rounds).

Like: "I've walked around this ground once." (I guess that this sounds really long and maybe it does not flow well)

> Walk/Run ten rounds of this ground.

Or

> Take/Walk ten laps of this ground.

A teacher asks a kid to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Running or walking, it doesn't really matter to the grammar.

A "lap" is a widely-understood word to describe a measured, roughly circular route. Running or walking, it doesn't really matter to the grammar:

> I walked three laps of the field.
>   I ran three laps of the field.

Another word you might use in place of it is "circuits".

A "round" is not a word I have heard to describe a circular walk or run. Perhaps you mean *around*, as in:

> I ran *around* the field three times.

Comment: And does it sound okay: "Take two laps of the ground" or should it be "run/Walk ten laps of the ground"? (Teacher says this to a student)

Comment: If I walk around the basketball court (just a walk); we were asked to. Will it be okay to say: "I walked two laps of the basketball court."

Comment: you could just say *do two laps*. A lap doesn't have to be circular (in the sense of being a circle shape), it can be a square/triangle/rectangle. It is circular as it finishes where it starts. Consider Grand Prix circuits - they are not shaped like circles - they are quite irregular - but they do finish where they start, and so are circular in that sense. Cars do laps around these. THinking about it you could also use *circuits*. *I did 10 circuits of the forest*

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish - You would not say "...of the ground," since **ground** as a singular/uncountable noun means "the dirt under my feet," not a specified area like the an athletic field.  You can use **grounds** in the plural to mean "the property belonging to a building," so a "lap of the school grounds," means a run or walk around the entire perimeter of the school property.

Comment: @CanadianYankee can it be "**I did ten laps around the school premises**." . And "**I did 10 laps around the basketball court**". **I did not run; just walked...** So is "laps" used only with "running" or can it be used for "walking and returning to the same point again"?

Comment: And @Smock will it be natural to use "walk/run" instead of "do" with "laps"? "I walked/ran a lap." instead of "I did a lap". (Because it doesn't tell whether it was covered running or walking .... Maybe it'll be okay when aren't trying to sound precise or maybe when "walking" or "running" are clear (i.e. whether we've been asked to walk or run laps..)

Comment: @CanadianYankee You could use *laps of the ground* if you mean a football/sports ground (that you were training in).

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish *I ran a lap* yes. It would be odd to *walk a lap*, though not incorrect (why would you walk laps? unless practicing for a walking race?)

Comment: Like I walked around the playground (maybe just taking a walk), will it be termed as "walking a lap"? I read it on a website too @Smock

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish It could be yes, as long as you finish where you start

Comment: @Smock at my school we walk in groups around the basketball court each day. So I was looking for my friend, and when I found her I said: "I did one lap looking for you." Or "I walked around the basketball court looking for you". (There are a lot of other kids walking too, so it's a bit crowded). So what sounds the best out of the two ?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Yes you could definitely use laps for that, as long as you are walking all the way around the edge of it and come back to where you started. (how big is the basketball court?)

Comment: @Smock - Okay, I think that's an AmE vs. BrE difference. I don't find "football ground" to be idiomatic as a speaker of AmE, but I get lots of google hits for British newspaper articles with that phrase. According to google ngram, it's about 10x more common in BrE than in AmE.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Yeah most likely they are all stadiums in Am? Just for ref here it is in cambs dictionary (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ground) 3rd meaning - *an area of land used for a particular purpose or activity* - What would you call a Parade Ground in AmE?

Comment: @Smock A "stadium" is a building (possibly without a roof) - if it's outdoors, it's a playing "field". The phrase "parade ground" is used here (also "parade ground**s**"), but "ground" really isn't used with a sports **field**. "Playground" is is common, but only as a single word - you can't separate out the "ground" as a descriptor.